# Recursive array search returns reference of sub array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a variable, `$nav`.

I have a function that will return a sub-array of `$nav`.

I would like to edit this sub-array as a reference to `$nav`.

Here is the code I use to do it, with some test code to see whether the references are working:

```
$group =& $this->find($parent, $this->nav);

$group['group'] = 'group'; // NOT a reference

private function find($needle, &$haystack) {

    $haystack['haystack'] = 'haystack'; // still a reference

    foreach ($haystack as &$sel) {

        $sel['sel'] = 'sel'; // BOTH a reference and not??

        if ($sel['link']->getSlug() == $needle)
            return $sel;

    }

}
```

Here are the var dumps:

`$group` dump:

```
Array
(
    [link] => Link Object
        (
            [text:Link:private] => root
            [slug:Link:private] => root
            [url:Link:private] => /root
        )

    [sel] => sel
    [group] => group
)
```

`$nav` dump:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [link] => Link Object
                (
                    [text:Link:private] => root
                    [slug:Link:private] => root
                    [url:Link:private] => /root
                )

            [sel] => sel
        )

    [haystack] => haystack
)
```

Setting test values for the array shows that manipulating `$haystack` is affecting the reference to `$nav`. Editing the `$sel` variable in the foreach loop is BOTH a reference and not a reference (why?). Editing the `$group` variable shows that the reference was not passed through.

***ANSWER***
To get this to work, I needed to set the foreach variable to a reference, and also declare a return reference in the function `find()`. Here is the correct code:

```
$group =& $this->find($parent, $this->nav);

// edit `$group` here, which will edit 
// the returned reference of the sub-array of `$this->nav`

private function &find($needle, &$haystack) {

foreach ($haystack as &$sel) {

    if ($sel['link']->getSlug() == $needle)
        return $sel;

}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what your array `$nav/$group` should look like before and after the function?  I don't see where you actually act on any variables once inside your function.  I also don't see why you would need to pass in the array by reference.  You can always act on the array in your function and then return the manipulated array when you are finished.  Perhaps I'm not understanding what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my post to show what I'm trying to do with the array.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if `$group` gives you what you want, is there some reason you can't use it??

Comment: If I could take it and pop it easily into `$nav`, I would be totally okay with that. But I want it to have an unlimited number of sub-arrays. So I'm not sure how to find exactly where to pop the `$group` in.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well one thing I can tell you so far is that to assign by reference you need to use the ampersand with the assignment operator.  `$group = &$this->find($parent, $this->nav);` should be `$group =& $this->find($parent, $this->nav);`

Comment: I have changed my code to reflect what you typed, but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: I'm posting an answer that should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, I'm still a little confused what exactly you are trying to achieve.  However, looking at your code you are passing in `$this->nav` as a reference (which appears fine and dandy) but inside your function I don't see where `$this->nav` (now `$haystack`) is actually being manipulated.  Also in a `foreach` loop the value you are working with needs to be passed as a reference in order to manipulate it.

So your current code of:

```
private function find($needle, &$haystack) { //$haystack points to $this->nav
  foreach ($haystack as $sel) {  //$sel is a copy of the value in $this->nav not a reference
    if (isset($sel['sub']))
      $this->find($needle, $sel['sub']);
    if ($sel['link']->getSlug() == $needle)
      return $sel;
  }
}
```

Therefore your `$this->nav` array isn't actually getting manipulated at all.  Whay *may* help is if you modify your `foreach` to use a reference as well.

`foreach($haystack as &$sel)`

This will cause `$sel` to reference the actual value in `$haystack` (instead of copying it) and since `$haystack` is already a reference you *should* be working with your `$this->nav` variable.

If things get too murky after that you may wish to reconsider your implementation a little.

Comment: I have edited my original post to be more clear. And you were right about the foreach, that is now working (although very oddly to me - acting as a reference and NOT as a reference). EDIT: I wasn't originally planning on actually editing anything in the find function, I wanted it to basically return the array in which I would put my new sub-array. Maybe you're right in that I should rethink the implementation.

Comment: Aha! I once I made your corrections, to get `$group` to be a reference, I needed to add the ampersand in front of the function declaration.

Comment: Nice to hear, glad you got things going!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is store references to the elements of the $nav array. If this is the case then this should work:

```
private function find($needle, &$haystack) {
  foreach ($haystack as &$sel) {
    if (isset($sel['sub']))
      $this->find($needle, $sel['sub']);
    if ($sel['link']->getSlug() == $needle)
      return &$sel;
  }
}
```

You need to pass the array you want to the function by reference, then specify in the foreach that the element is a reference, then return the reference to that element otherwise php will automatically get the value that the reference refers to and store it in a new chunk of memory.